# android preferences - choose file from sdcard

Tags: android-preferences, android

In the app I am working on i want to give the user the possibility to choose a (audio) file from the sdcard in the preference settings. Completely blocked right now, how to go about achieving this, preferable of course with standard methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implements your own file explorer and retrieve the result from the picking

There is a very simple project which provides such a feature [here](https://github.com/Kaloer/Android-File-Picker-Activity)

You can set the file type you want to filter etc

Comment: thx - i found a couple of file explorer. what i am blocked about at the moment is how i link this to the preference screen.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you launch your file explorer ? Do you start it with startActivityForResult ? Since PreferenceActivity are Activity you can retrieve the result in onActivityResult